# express svg image element rendering issue in safari/firefox

Tags: express, d3.js, reactjs, svg

I'm building a react app on express 4, part of the app is a graph I'm building using d3. I having a problem with any images held within the svg tag on safari and firefox (but not chrome) eg:

```
<svg width="1373.6499999999999" height="250">
  <g transform="translate(20,20)" >
  <image href="/images/withdrawal.png" class="withdrawal" x="100.84925373134327" y="72.41613009407105" width="30" height="30">
   </image></g></svg>
```

It essentially renders on the page where it should be but just blank:

[image]

I've tried with different file types and with full urls. I've tried different doctypes but that doesn't seem to be getting me anywhere.

There's lot of documentation out there about issues with the image tag not rendering on safari but as far as I can tell the closest thing that could be the problem is the content type header, which I haven't had any success with. I tried the svg outside of react and I still get the same problem.

I know as an alternative I could just append an img to the graph instead but I'd like to try and avoid that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `href` attribute of the `<image>` element is not part of the SVG namespace. It belongs to the [XLink](http://www.w3.org/TR/xlink/) namespace instead. Therefore, you need to add the namespace declaration and prefix the attribute accordingly (most often seen as [`xlink:href`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#ImageElementHrefAttribute)). For your code this means:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     width="1373.6499999999999" height="250">
  <g transform="translate(20,20)" >
    <image xlink:href="/images/withdrawal.png" class="withdrawal" x="100.84925373134327" y="72.41613009407105" width="30" height="30">
    </image>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: I tried something like that but I get an error message saying ReactJSX is not XML

Comment: @TimMcLoone This may help: [*"Embedding SVG into ReactJS"*](/q/23402542)

Comment: Ahhh I bet that will do it! I'll give it a try tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: That fixed the problem, I'm still a bit confused though because this example works perfectly and doesn't have any of the xml tags http://bl.ocks.org/mpmckenna8/b87df1c44243aa1575cb

Comment: @TimMcLoone That seems to be a browser [issue](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/d3-js/Sh4ysLFBMRQ/hHjzBP0bX1oJ) when serializing the DOM in the inspector. However, the fact that you are not able to see them does not mean, that they are not there. Try running the following command in your console on the example you linked to: `d3.selectAll("image").filter(function() { return d3.select(this).attr("href"); }).node().attributes.href.namespaceURI`. This will print the correct XLink namespace for the first image having an `href` attribute.

Comment: @TimMcLoone Reading Amelia's answer to [*"Is it possible to use HTML's .querySelector() to select by xlink attribute in an SVG?"*](/q/23034283) it seems to be an attribute which is notoriously hard to get to.